# connect phonegap developer app to xampp database

Tags: php, android, cordova

I am developing an android app. I use Phonegap Desktop(on my desktop) and PhoneGap developer app( on my Android device) for testing the app. Before setting a local database in my app, i could test my app via PhoneGap desktop and the PhoneGap developer app just with specifying the server address which is available at the bottom of PhoneGap Desktop (http://192.168.x.x). 
Now i have made a php connection to my database which is on my C: drive in /xmapp/htdocs folder. I can still make connection with my app with the PhoeGap Developer app, but i can not access my local database.  On my desktop and the local browser everything works just fine with the database and the app.Any idea how that works? I need some way to connect the Phonegap Developer app to my local databse.
Any help is appreciated!

here is de code in my index.html

```
function pasuser(form) 
    {           
    var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
                var json = JSON.parse(response);
                if(json.success == 0)
                {
                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=response;
                }
                else if(json.success == 1)
                {
                    window.location.href = 'http://localhost/WebStore/watches.html';
                }
            }
        }

        var login = document.getElementById("login").value;
        var passw = document.getElementById("password").value;

        xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/xampp/api/2/inloggen.php?emailadres=" + login + "&ww=" + passw,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Comment: you haven't posted the code so i cannot know for sure but i think there is problem in your httprequest and response statements or maybe json parsing. provide the code

Comment: Hi Shashnak, I have put the code in the index.html. Can you look if that is enough. Actually this code works just fine as i mentioned in the local browser. the problem is connection with the tester app (PhoneGap Developer app)

Comment: you are using localhost use the ip address instead when you connect your phone it starts using its own localserver which causes problem. try by replacing it with ip address. if thats not the case then the problem is in apps code.

Comment: You mean by ip address the localhost ip : 127.0.0.1 or just the 192.168.x.x on the developer app? Or should i use them both i different lines?

Comment: Actually neither of these two works. But if there is a problem in the apps code, how can i login through the local browser? Actually the index.html is the only page that i have. Do you have some other suggestions?